# Raspberry Pi 3 Initial Setup Failed

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card, noobs, setup

I am trying to install Raspbian into Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, but failing every time. I tried to do it in two ways:

1. NOOBS way: 
   First I copied the contents of the NOOBS folder into my Brand new Micro SD card (16GB, Class 10) after formatting it. 
   Then I inserted SD card into the RPi3, with all the peripherals connected and turned it on. 
   The NOOBS initializes perfectly and shows a dialog box with the names of the OSes, I select raspbian and click install. 
   When the installation starts, suddenly the multicolored screen appears after about 30 secs and reboots NOOBS. And shows the OS dialog box screen again. 
   This switching of screens happens with noise from the RPi.
2. Etching the OS image directly to the SD card:
   I flashed the Raspbian OS image directly onto the SD card using Etcher for Windows 10. 
   I inserted this SD card back on to the Raspberry Pi and turned it on and it shows four raspberries on the top left and then a black screen. This happens repeatedly.

I use Micro SD card of 16GB and Class 10. The battery adapter is of Samsung brand 5.0-2.0A. I format the SD card before copying the NOOBS files or flashing it with the OS image.

I've been trying to find a solution online, but no progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, yet to find a solution. You can refer some of the comments against my question, may be the resolution suggested for me may work for you, try it. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74002/new-raspberry-pi-continues-to-reboot-with-not-a-iso3166-code#

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a power issue. The Raspberry Pi 3 is very sensitive to both voltage and current. Try a certified power supply.