# New Raspberry PI continues to reboot with not a ISO3166 code

Tags: pi-3

I have downloaded NOOBS onto a 32GB samsung sd card.  After powering up PI for a brief period it shows the option to select Raspbian OS or another but before I can select any it continues to reboot with the error ... not a ISO3166 code.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the locale or something. have you made any settings that affect language or other aspects like keyboard layout?

Comment: nope.  I have not even been able to get to install Raspian pi OS through the NOOBS SD card (manually created SD card).  As per suggestion by Mike below, I flashed the Raspbian Stretch with Desktop using Etcher and this time the Raspbian image kept coming on the screen (3 of them) but post that nothing displays on the viewsonic monitor connected via HDMI to DVI adapter.  Along with the above change, I also switched the power supply to 5V-2A samsung mobile charger.  Earlier the power supply I was using was providing very low current < 700mA.

Comment: Since I could not get the display to work which I thought could be due to power issue as well, I thought of connecting to raspberry pi without monitor.  I connected the pi via LAN cables to a router and then trying to connect to it via ssh to the pi which kicks me out saying connection reset by peer and then subsequently connection closed by peer.

Answer (score 1):

Download 'Raspbian Stretch with Desktop' and flash that direct to your sd card using Etcher.

Instructions :
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md

Raspbian image :
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Etcher :
https://etcher.io

Comment: Thank you Mike.  I reflashed as instructed above.  This time however, I am seeing 3 raspberry icon on my screen and continues to go to blank screen and then displays 3 raspberry icon and the cycle repeats.  FYI, I am using a DVI monitor with a HDMI male to DVI female converter for the display.  I have connected a USB keyboard and a mouse.

Comment: I was using the power supply bought from Amazon (DIY Retails 3.3V and 5V Power Supply Module for MB102 Bread Board Arduino Raspberry Pi, Black).  I noted that it has current output of < 700ma.  I could not gracefully power off and had to switch off the power supply.  I then connected my samsung mobile charger which had a 5V with 2A current rating.  This time the Raspberry Pi screen came up and then vanished altogether.  I am seeing black screen now.  Please suggest.

Comment: Which model of Pi are you using? What resolution is your monitor?

Comment: I am using Pi 3 model B bought about 2 weeks back.  I am using VA1912wb monitor from viewsonic and it has a resolution of 1440 x 900

Comment: this time PI seems to be stable, but due to the display problem, I tried login in to the PI using SSH after connecting it to the router through LAN cable.  I am getting connection reset by peer when I do SSH.  The login prompt itself does not come.  FYI, I created a "ssh" file in the root of the SD card and the screen showed that I should run a config script to reset the password.  However after this the display is going blank, hence I tried to login via ssh and faced another issue as noted above.

Comment: On the machine that you used to flash the sd card, put the sd card back in, are you able to see the boot folder and the config.txt file ? If so edit the file and set ‘hdmi_group=2’ and ‘hdmi_mode=47’. Then place back in the Pi and boot.

Comment: I edited the config.txt file and tried the above, the result seems to be the same.  I tried the hdmi_safe=1 also with the same result.  Interestingly though, the pi seems to recognize each of the modes as the display of the berry symbol was either correct or large (in the safe mode).  It shows the berry icon (now 4 in number) and after sometime, shows welcome to raspberry pi then some log statements below, waits with a prompt to say that SSH is enabled and the default password ... etc. after pressing ok, the screen goes blank.

Comment: Try taking out the hdmi_safe=1 and using hdmi_group=2 and hdmi_mode=46 (from https://elinux.org/RPiconfig )

Comment: tried that too mike, same result.  After pressing OK to the SSH warning message, the screen goes blank.  then I went to default config.txt and now connected the pi through to Panasonic Plasma HD TV through HDMI cable.  The result is the same.  It initially display 4 berry's and then welcome screen and then SSH warning and then goes blank on the TV too.  Why would it display everything else properly upto this stage and then decide to go blank?  Could it be that I am connecting it to a power supply that is 5V-2A??  FYI, I have connected USB keyboard and mouse as well.

Comment: If your connected via hdmi to a tv - remove the hdmi_group and hdmi_mode settings - it should auto detect. It could be the power supply, I always recommend the official 5.1V 2.5A 18awg cable power supply for a Pi3. Do you see the desktop with the road and sky background image?

Comment: You could also try re-flashing the sd card again - it could have been corrupted when connected to the 700ma psu.

Comment: nope, I did not see a road and sky background image.  I had removed the hdmi_group and hdmi_mode settings when I tried with the TV.  I have ordered for 5V-3A power supply (https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B075XMHTTY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).